# How to use templates to display fields from two tables (using FK)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

In my template, I would like to show 'challenges' grouped by 'category' e.g.

Category 1

- Challenge 1
- Challenge 2

Category 2

- Challenge 3
- Challenge 4

Here is my models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=400)

class Challenge(models.Model):
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In my template file I want to do something like this:

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    {{ category.title }}
    <ul>
        {% for challenge in Challenge.objects.get(category_id=category.id) %}
        <li>{{ challenge.question_text }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

But I understand you cannot call functions in templates. How else can I display data from two sets in a relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your category_list is a QuerySet you can get related challenge values through [Many-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    {{ category.title }}
    <ul>
        {% for challenge in category.challenge_set.all %}
        <li>{{ challenge.question_text }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```